# Can I use a client constructed session token for cosmosdb?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, consistency

I've done a bit of research on using session token in cosmosdb's dotnet v3 sdk, and so far I found these two links that give me some hints on how to use it: [utilize-session-tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-consistency?tabs=portal%2Cdotnetv2%2Capi-async#utilize-session-tokens) and [how-to-convert-session-token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-convert-session-token).

In our scenario, we would like to have strong consistency (but we don't want to use strong consistency for all data) if the update belongs to the same `userId`, so that when one instance updates data under this user, everyone else will immediately see the result.
We'd also want to use cosmosdb as a lock for another scenario.

However, the links above only show how to reuse a token that was returned from creating a document. And I wonder if I can construct my own session token and use it for strong consistency.

For example, if I want to update the data under a specific `userId` I would use `{userId}:-1#1` as the session token. Would that be a valid way to use the session token? I'm also not sure what the fields pkrangeid, Version, GlobalLSN mean and what role they play when cosmosdb deals with consistency.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The session token includes the LSN that cannot be created by the client. Session token must be issued by the service as it is the only way to provide the consistency guarantees for Session consistency.

To get *in-region strong* consistency, or more accurately, *read your own write* guarantees provided by Session consistency and are using a single instance of the Cosmos client you will already get read your own write guarantees. You do not need to manage the Session token. The Cosmos SDK does it for you.

If you have a scenario where you have multiple instances of the Cosmos DB client in separate processes and your want *read your own write* guarantees, you have two options.

1. Implement bounded staleness consistency which provides *in-region strong* consistency for all Cosmos client instances reading and writing in that region. It does this by reading two replicas. Since Cosmos DB always writes to 3 replicas, you are guaranteed to always read the most current data as Cosmos DB will check the LSN from both replicas and return the data from the higher LSN if they don't match. The upside for this approach is that it is super easy to implement. The downside is that point reads (i.e. ReadItemAsync()) cost twice as much because its reading from two replicas.
2. Use Session consistency and use Stateful Entities in Durable Functions or something similar that will allow you to implement a distributed mutex to store and update the Session token across multiple Cosmos client instances. Upside here is point reads are still 1 RU, downside is this complexity and also all writes are serialized as they require queuing all writes up against the mutex which needs to be updated by each client instance. Note: if your clients are in the same process but on multiple threads, you could use a Concurrent Collection which is simpler but still requires synchonizing threads so will impact write throughput in the client when there is high concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! 
I still have a couple of questions: 
Does that mean session tokens can only be used for read/query requests, and has to be updated by every write request? What about the replace request with ifEtagMatch flag set, how do I guarantee the etag is new? Also, if I want to maintain this distributed mutex to store the Session token, do I store a session token per db or per partition? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have another question. In doc, if a Bounded Staleness database is spanned across multiple regions with a single master, it degrades to Consistent Prefix consistency. In our case, the reads and writes will only occur in the same region as master (multi-region for DR only), is it still Strong or it's Consistent Prefix in this particular, master region?

Comment: I also tried using an arbitrary large LSN for the session token on a newly created db, but it wasn't giving me any errors, was the token I passed in not processed?

Comment: Session token is updated on each write request, including Replace and Upsert. Etag is checked when you set IfMatchEtag = itemResponse.ETag in the ItemRequestOptions parameter for Replace or Upsert, example here, https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L724

Comment: For single region reads you will get strong consistency with bounded staleness. See Consistency Guarantees here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#guarantees-associated-with-consistency-levels

Comment: You cannot set the LSN. I don't know how it is handled in backend but it is probably being ignored.

Comment: btw, please mark the answer as accepted if no more questions. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBrown, I have another question. If we used CSharp's Task.WhenAll to do our writes (ie. 100 calls to CreateItemAsync). How do we get the latest session token to pass on to the next application?